# avoid <noscript> tag of HTML

Tags: html, browser, firefox-addon, noscript

some firefox extentions can avoid `<audio>` `<video>` or many html tags. for example [noscript](http://noscript.net/) plugin deletes all `<script>` tag and inside function.

***my question: can i avoid `<noscript>` tag as well and how?***

**for quality standarts:**

this is html

```
<div><noscript>somethings</noscript></div>
<div><h1>kel</h1></div>
```

i want my browser read it like

```
<div></div>
<div><h1>kel</h1></div>
```

like there is no `<noscript>` tag at all

**EDIT**

***++plus question++***

there is no option on [noscript](http://noscript.net/) addon even if it can hide `<audio>` `<video>` and many other things. Do you know why is that? Has anyone hear about "it isn'T allowed hiding `<noscript>` tags" or something like that?

Comment: Why is this something you want?  If JavaScript is enabled, then `<noscript>` tags will be hidden, and then you can just use JavaScript to get rid of them.  Or are you trying to make an extension to remove `<noscript>` tags?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: This question would be better suited on the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Comment: @RocketHazmat firstly `<noscript>` tags donT be hidden(there are still there) and how can i use Javascript to get rid of them? i don't know anything about it.

Comment: @user3301042 Do you have Javascript enabled? If not, then [that's what the `<noscript>` tags are for](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element): to provide you with an alternative.

Comment: @Carsten i have javascript disabled and website says to me you can't  use this site without javascript. Thats why i want it. i want to use site javascript disabled

Comment: If the site's saying that, it's saying it for a reason - because the site won't work or will be severely disabled without JS.

Comment: Just a question - why do you have JS disabled?

Comment: @user3301042: So, you want an extension that will hide `<noscript>` tags from browsers when you have JavaScript disabled via noscript (the extension)?

Comment: @ArtOfCode: I'm assuming because of [NoScript](http://noscript.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of them, you can use JavaScript or jQuery to remove them:

```
// jQuery
$("noscript").remove();

// JS
var noscript = document.getElementsByTagName("noscript");
for(var i=0; i<noscript.length; i++) {
    noscript[i].parentNode.removeChild(noscript[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: from following the comment string, it would appear you want to get rid of them from the console. Open the console and type the following in:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js";
$("noscript").remove();
```

Alternatively, you can just use the pure JS above.

Comment: but i can't do this to another one's website, can i?

Comment: Yes you can - see the EDIT section.

Comment: even if i couldn't do it i'll give you an up vote.meanwhile  when i use enter, js console of google run my code but i want to go to next line instead. how can i do that?

Comment: Hit Shift-Enter instead, it adds a new line. Alternatively copy/paste it.